# How to attach an image into a bottom middle of a div?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to achieve the following:

[image]

And I largely have.  The only missing piece is the Svg of the downward arrow.  I need it to be in the middle of the div (the green part) irregardless of how wide the div is.  I've tried setting `.listing-price:after.left` to 50% but I don't think it does what it should.  I also want the arrow to attach to the bottom of the main div, but I got it there by hardwiring the `.listing-price:after.top` property.

1. How do I get the arrow to be in the middle?
2. Is there a better way of attaching the arrow to the bottom of the div than hardwiring the `.top` property?

Here is what I have so far:

```css
body {
  background-color: salmon;
  transform: scale(3.0);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.listing-price {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "museo_sans_rounded", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #009934;
  border-color: #F2F5F3;  
}

/* Favorite Marker */
.listing-price:before {
  content: url(https://rgelb.github.io/public/misc/heart_icon.svg);
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -7.8px;
  top: -6px;
}

/* Downward arrow */
.listing-price:after {
  content: url(https://rgelb.github.io/public/misc/arrow_border.svg);
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 10px;
}

.listing-price-open-new-house {
  background-color: #586371;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-spacing: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  font-family: "museo_sans_rounded", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: -1px;
  line-height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: -11px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
  <div style="height: 25px;margin-top: 40px;">
    <div class="listing-price">
      <i class="listing-price-open-new-house">Open</i>
      $258K
    </div>    
    <div class="listing-price">
      <i class="listing-price-open-new-house">Open</i>
      $9M
    </div>        
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're lucky, it works just by setting `left:0;width:100%;` for the arrow:

```css
body {
  background-color: salmon;
  transform: scale(3.0);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.listing-price {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "museo_sans_rounded", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #009934;
  border-color: #F2F5F3;  
}

/* Favorite Marker */
.listing-price:before {
  content: url(https://rgelb.github.io/public/misc/heart_icon.svg);
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -7.8px;
  top: -6px;
}

/* Downward arrow */
.listing-price:after {
  content: url(https://rgelb.github.io/public/misc/arrow_border.svg);
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8.9px; /* a bit of fine-tuning */
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.listing-price-open-new-house {
  background-color: #586371;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-spacing: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  font-family: "museo_sans_rounded", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: -1px;
  line-height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: -11px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
  <div style="height: 25px;margin-top: 40px;">
    <div class="listing-price">
      <i class="listing-price-open-new-house">Open</i>
      $258K
    </div>    
    <div class="listing-price">
      <i class="listing-price-open-new-house">Open</i>
      $9M
    </div>        
  </div>
```

The reason why this works lies in the nature of SVGs: if the top-level `<svg>` element contains a `viewBox` attribute defining the area to draw, and there are a `width` and `height` defined for the element where the aspect ratio does not fit that of the viewBox, the viewBox content will be scaled and positioned such that it is fitted at the largest possible size into the middle of the box defined by the svg element.

So, by setting `width` to the width of the div, you get the positioning in the middle for free - provided the SVG has a viewBox attribute (which it has), and no `preserveAspectRatio` attribute changing this behavior (which it hasn't).